# Cx-Freeze Error - Python 34

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a Cx_Freeze setup file that I am trying to make work.  What is terribly frustrating is that it *used* to Freeze appropriately.  Now, however, I get the following error:

> > edit. the error that shows up is not a Python exception through the console, but a crash report when attempting to launch the resulting exe file generated through the freeze.

'File 'notetest.py', line 1, in 
_find_and_load   importlib_bootstrap.py, line 2214

....

```
AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute '_fix_up_module'
```

My setup.py file follows:

```
    import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': [], 'excludes' : []}
base = 'Win32GUI'
exe = Executable(
    script = 'notetest.py',
    initScript = None,
    base = 'Win32GUI',
    targetName = 'MedicaidAid.exe',
    compress = True,
    appendScriptToExe = True,
    appendScriptToLibrary = True,
    icon = None
)

setup( name = 'MedicaidAid', 
        version = '0.85',
        description = 'MedicaidAid Software',
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable('notetest.py', base = base)])
```

Comment: Just to be sure: the application runs fine and cx-freeze can freeze the actual code with which older version of Python?

Comment: Trilarion, yes the application runs fine through the IDE. Cx-freeze runs through the entire code and appears to work just fine, no errors or whatnot.  I currently have Python 3.4.1 as the working "path python", and have written the program in Python 3x.  The previous version of Python it worked under was Python 3.3. I have tried removing the offending version of python, to no success.  Thanks for any thoughts you might have.

Comment: I found this related thread that seems to address a similar (if not the same) problem. I will try it and report back.   https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/61/python-340-nameerror-name-__file__-is-not

Comment: It appears it might be something to do with Python 3.4.  I uninstalled all python versions and tried 3.4 and then 3.3.  Python 3.3 works w/o this error.

Comment: I think it's very likely an error within Cx_Freeze (or Python 3.4). Maybe you could open your own issue on their bitbucket site, if you want to help them. Alternatively wait a bit. Good to know actually.

Comment: good idea Tril.  I've opened up an issue on bitbucket for them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should install cx_freeze from this [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze). It contains an important patch that solves the problem (see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.python/Ubagx7NDtJE/_47ZP2Uj-BUJ) discussion for detailed).

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is a known issue with Cx_Freeze. [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/81/python-34-venv-importlib-attributeerror).

Apparently there is a compiling error that occurs.  The bitbucket link lists the work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution by Northcat worked just perfectly. The issue of missing patch in the other `cx_freeze` came into picture while installing(some alert messages were thrown) it.  It is this missing patch because of which the alerts were given. The new installation from this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) had no such alerts while installing and it so worked fine.