# use cx_freeze with mysql-connector

Tags: python, mysql, cx-freeze, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to make an exe program from a fully functional python 3.4 script, but I can't embed the dependencies about official mysql connector.
This is a sample code with the problem:

```
import mysql.connector
from settings import *

connLocal  = mysql.connector.connect( host   =  DB_CRM_HOST,
                                      user   =  DB_CRM_USER,
                                      passwd =  DB_CRM_PASS,
                                      db     =  DB_CRM_DB )
cursorLocal = connLocal.cursor ()
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Users"
cursorLocal.execute( sqlStr)
for row in  cursorLocal.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

and this is my setup script:

```
'''script per il setup'''
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

EXCLUDES = ['_ssl',  # Exclude _ssl
            'pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest', 'locale',
            'optparse', 'pickle', 'calendar']  # Exclude standard library
PACKAGES = []
INCLUDES = []
SCRIPT_NAME = "sync_crm2web.py"
EXE_NAME = "sync_crm2web.exe"
PRJ_NAME = "sync_crm2web"
VERSION = 1.0
AUTHOR = "Antonio"
DESCRIPTION = "Sincronizzazione crm sito internet"
BASE = "Console" #"Win32GUI"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD_EXE_OPTIONS = {"packages": PACKAGES,
                     "excludes": EXCLUDES,
                     "includes": INCLUDES,
                     "path": sys.path,
                     'append_script_to_exe':False,
                     'build_exe':"dist/bin",
                     'compressed':True,
                     'copy_dependent_files':True,
                     'create_shared_zip':True,
                     'include_in_shared_zip':True,
                     'optimize':2,}

EXE = Executable(script=SCRIPT_NAME,
                 base=BASE,
                 compress=True,
                 targetDir="dist",
                 targetName=EXE_NAME,
                 initScript=None,
                 copyDependentFiles=True,
                 appendScriptToExe=True,
                 appendScriptToLibrary=False,
)

setup(name=PRJ_NAME,
      version=VERSION,
      author=AUTHOR,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      options={"build_exe": BUILD_EXE_OPTIONS},
      executables=[EXE])
```

also trying forcing PACKAGES = [], INCLUDES = [] with combination of mysql, mysql-connector, mysql.connector seem not to work.

I always obtain:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "sync_crm2web.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2189, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2201, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Can someone help me? full cx_freeze log here http://pastebin.com/S3TMzAnB

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, please describe what goes wrong, e.g. what errors you see. Also, the log from freezing might have useful information - can you put that into a pastebin and give a link?

Comment: Thank's I've added the necessary information

Answer (score 1):

Solved using input from [Cx-Freeze Error - Python 34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920073/cx-freeze-error-python-34)  - [www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) so I've installed cx_Freeze from this installer and not from PIP.

After that I've commented the needed **_ssl** module and place all library ('build_exe' property) in the same folder of the executable.

```
'''script per il setup'''
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

EXCLUDES = [#'_ssl',  # !!!! COMMENTED !!!!
            'pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest', 'locale',
            'optparse', 'pickle', 'calendar']  # Exclude standard library
PACKAGES = []
INCLUDES = []
SCRIPT_NAME = "sync_crm2web.py"
EXE_NAME = "sync_crm2web.exe"
PRJ_NAME = "sync_crm2web"
VERSION = 1.0
AUTHOR = "Antonio"
DESCRIPTION = "Sincronizzazione crm sito internet"
BASE = "Console" #"Win32GUI"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD_EXE_OPTIONS = {"packages": PACKAGES,
                     "excludes": EXCLUDES,
                     "includes": INCLUDES,
                     "path": sys.path,
                     'append_script_to_exe':False,
                     'build_exe':"dist", # !!!! BEFORE WAS dist/bin !!!!
                     'compressed':True,
                     'copy_dependent_files':True,
                     'create_shared_zip':True,
                     'include_in_shared_zip':True,
                     'optimize':2,}

EXE = Executable(script=SCRIPT_NAME,
                 base=BASE,
                 compress=True,
                 targetDir="dist",
                 targetName=EXE_NAME,
                 initScript=None,
                 copyDependentFiles=True,
                 appendScriptToExe=True,
                 appendScriptToLibrary=False,
)

setup(name=PRJ_NAME,
      version=VERSION,
      author=AUTHOR,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      options={"build_exe": BUILD_EXE_OPTIONS},
      executables=[EXE])
```